# Search API for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: google-api, windows-phone-8.1, bing-search

I'm developing an app on Windows Phone 8.1. I would like to let users type a name of a place, a restaurant for example, as an autocomplete event, and retrieve all the related places according to the name of the restaurant. Did somebody use something like that on windows phone 8.1 ? Is There a **google place api** that can be used for Windows Phone 8.1  or a nice **Bing Search api** ? About the last option, could someone confirm that we need to pay that service according to the number of transactions (requests)?

Comment: What an answer do you expect? A list to the API documentations? All you mentioned is possible using the Google Places API, Bing has some API as well, but you could also use Yelp or the Foursquare APIs. Or combine all of them. In general, you don't have to pay for using them - it depends on the amount of requests your app creates (...rate limit).

Answer (score 1):

So you would like to use some service which offers that data either for free or at some cost? There is no such general purpose service, but you can leverage some existing:

- Foursqare has a list of places nearby. These often include Batcave or Hogwarts though.
- Google Places - https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

You can build a startup around correct places search API :)